# Does SleepEx guarantee that all pending completion callbacks get called before timeout?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I have a C++ program that uses overlapped IO for network communication. The main thread has a loop that calls `SleepEx(5, true);`. There are also two TCP sockets. I assume that the completion callbacks are called during the alertable wait. Assume also that by the time `SleepEx` gets called both of my TCP connections have received some data. Now the question is what happens if the first completion callback takes longer than 5ms? Does the `SleepEx` return after calling the first callback or does it also call the second callback? In other words does the `SleepEx` guarantee to call **ALL** of the scheduled completion callbacks? This is not clear because the documentation says it will return when at least one of the events meet...

Comment: This doesn't matter to a program that's robust against race conditions. An I/O can complete literally **while** `SleepEx` is returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code must not assume that both APCs will be called before SleepEx() returns.  Conversely, it must not assume that a pending APC will *not* be called simply because the specified wait period has expired.

The only behaviour that you can rely upon is that if one or more APCs are pending, at least one will be executed.

Generally speaking, best practice is to wait for APCs in a loop that does nothing else, using an infinite timeout in the wait.  If you need to do something periodically, you can use a [waitable timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to [generate an APC periodically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use WaitForSingleObjectEx() or WaitForMultipleObjectsEx() to detect when a waitable timer or other synchronization object is triggered, while still handling APCs.

However, if you must perform some periodic action that cannot be handled in an APC or be triggered by a synchronization object, you can use nested loops: the inner loop does nothing but call the wait repeatedly (with a timeout period reduced by however long the loop has already been running) and the outer loop performs the periodic action.

If you must perform some periodic action that cannot be delayed by pending APCs, you will need to do it in a separate thread.  Note that because Windows is not a real-time OS, you will still not be able to guarantee that any given action will take place within any particular timeframe, although you can reduce the risk by increasing the thread priority.

Comment: Thanks, I've got the idea. The problem is actually I have a waitable timer that sends the requests over 2 TCP connections every 5ms. So I expect to send two requests and receive 2 responses withing 5ms of SleepEx. And sometimes I see that only one TCP callback gets called over a significant amount of time (500ms). although the wireshark says that data in both connections was delivered. That makes me think that the system is too stressed and there is not enough time to process all completion calls within this 5ms.

Comment: @conceptacid: unless the callback itself is taking most of that 500ms, that's very unlikely.  There's probably just some minor glitch in the code.  If you can generate a MCVE you can post it as another question, or email me directly if you like (see my profile).

Comment: Thanks, I still believe that there is bug in my application, not in the SleepEx so I keep investigating....